# Can't push data to Firebase using JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read/write to firebase. I was able to perform reading successfully but can't seem to push data to it. Not sure what I'm doing wrong and the google documentation is too concise to help.. Have a look at my code below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as firebase from "firebase";

class Products extends Component {
  pushProduct() {
    const prodName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    const prodBrand = document.getElementById("brand").value;

    const newProdRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Products");

    var data = {
      prodBrand: prodBrand
      prodName: prodName,
    };
    newProdRef.push(data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <form style={{ border: "solid", borderWidth: "1px", width: "600px" }}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Product Name" id="name" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Brand" id="brand" />
          <button onClick={this.pushProduct}>Add Product</button>
        </form>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Products;
```

I get no errors except for a warning in chrome dev tools saying

> it is advisable to only import individual SDK components

Also my page seems to refresh every time I click the Add Product button

I've had no problems with this using Java but JavaScript seems to be my bane.
Help would greatly be appreciated.

When I push data within componentDidMount, it is done successfully

Comment: Can you log out your `data` object and see what it says? This is not typically how to read values from input components in React.

Comment: The data object is getting created just fine, I checked it.

Comment: If your code is exactly as written above then your IDE should be showing you have an error in your `data` object. The line that says `prodBrand: prodBrand` should say `prodBrand: prodBrand,`. It's missing a comma.

Comment: Your page refresh is also from the fact that your `<button>` is submitting the form by default. You need to add `type="button"` to prevent this behaviour or you can add the `event` parameter in your `pushProduct(event)` function and call event.preventDefault();

Comment: Lastly, are you initialising your firebase with your API keys? Because if you're initialising your firebase elsewhere you need to import the firebase instance that you initialised not the global firebase instance.

Comment: Thanks @blaytenshi , I fixed my button and imported the api keys from the separate class and it worked!!!

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear you got it working. Please Accept the answer so Stackoverflow can close this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your page refresh is also from the fact that your  is submitting the form by default. You need to add type="button" to prevent this behaviour or you can add the event parameter in your pushProduct(event) function and call event.preventDefault();